# Chrome "pageAction" not automatically shown in Chrome main toolbar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension and I'd like to show my extension icon in the main toolbar (on the right of the address bar) when the user is visiting a specific website.

I'm using the `chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id)` API but the problem I'm having is that the extension icon doesn't show up where I expect, but stays hidden in the little "puzzle"(1) dropdown where all the other extension are stored.

I would like not to ask my users to pin the extension, because doing so the icon would be visible even on web pages that are unrelated to my extension.

According to the [pageAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) documentation I should see the icon where I expect it to be, but for some reason it's not working as expected.

The only effect caused by calling `pageAction.show` seems to be that it enables my extension icon to be clicked to execute my custom `onClicked` listener.

My sample code is:

```
// background.js
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  alert('working?');
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (id, info, tab) {
  chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);
});
```

```
  "name": "my extension",

  [...]

  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/icon16.png",
      "48": "icons/icon48.png",
      "128": "icons/icon128.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Something"
  },
```

1. [image]

Comment: _the extension icon doesn't show up where I expect, but stays hidden in the little "puzzle"(1) dropdown where all the other extension are stored._ AFAIK this is normal behaviour. Every new extension is hidden there by default, and using `pageAction` (instead of `browserAction`) has no effect on it.

Comment: @hindmost so how is my user supposed to understand my extension is ready to perform some action when clicked if it's hidden in a dropdown? And why should my user be forced to pin the extension and have it visible on every tab if they just care about a specific website?

Comment: _so how is my user supposed to understand my extension is ready to perform some action when clicked if it's hidden in a dropdown?_ Obviously by pinning it. _And why should my user be forced to pin the extension and have it visible on every tab if they just care about a specific website?_ You have to ask the Google team that.